# Having different drop down menues?

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, radio-button

I want to be able to have different drop down menues appear when radio buttons are checked. Here is the code I have so far:

```
        <input checked="unchecked" type="Radio" name="gender" value="male" class="auto-style3" style="width: 20px">Male
            <input checked="unchecked" type="Radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
                                                <br>                                                                             
            <?php 

        $answer = $_POST['gender'];  
        if ($gender == "male") {          
            <select name="Select1">
    <option></option>
    <option>Floor</option>
    <option>Pommel</option>
    <option>Rings</option>
    <option>Vault</option>
    <option>P Bars</option>
    <option>High Bar</option>
        </select>;      
        }
        else {
            <select name="Select1">
    <option></option>
    <option>Vault</option>
    <option>Uneven Bars</option>
    <option>Beam</option>
    <option>Floor</option>

        </select>;
        }          
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<form name="yourform" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<input checked="unchecked" type="Radio" name="gender" value="male" class="auto-style3" style="width: 20px">Male
<input checked="unchecked" type="Radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php 
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {
    $answer = $_POST['gender'];  
    if ($answer == "male") {  ?>  

<select name="Select1">
<option></option>
<option>Floor</option>
<option>Pommel</option>
<option>Rings</option>
<option>Vault</option>
<option>P Bars</option>
<option>High Bar</option>
</select>       

    <?php } else { ?>

<select name="Select1">
<option></option>
<option>Vault</option>
<option>Uneven Bars</option>
<option>Beam</option>
<option>Floor</option>
</select>

<?php }} ?>
```

This will only work if you have posted the result of the "gender" radio, of course, since php is executed on server-side...

Comment: That comes up with "Notice: Undefined index: gender in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 55

Notice: Undefined variable: gender in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 56"

Comment: Line 55:  $answer = $_POST['gender'];
Line 56:  if ($gender == "male") {  ?>

Comment: sure it does since $gender has never been defined.. I updated my answer accordingly

Comment: The drop box doesn't appear.

Comment: since I'm bored to tears at work today, here's the complete solution.. please take some time to read up on the very basics of php!

Comment: I hope you do realize that you actually have to submit your choice
(click on one of the radios and then hit submit) to make the page reload and print the html code of your dropdown depending on your choice - above code works totally fine, if it doesn't for you, try `action=""` instead of `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Don't render HTML as a string in PHP.

Rather than break PHP code segment and write HTML code.

So, following is the correct answer:

```
<input checked="unchecked" type="Radio" name="gender" value="male" class="auto-style3" style="width: 20px">Male
<input checked="unchecked" type="Radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
<br>
<?php
$gender = (! empty($_POST['gender'])) ? $_POST['gender'] : 'male';
if ($gender == "male") {
?>       
<select name="Select1">
<option></option>
<option>Floor</option>
<option>Pommel</option>
<option>Rings</option>
<option>Vault</option>
<option>P Bars</option>
<option>High Bar</option>
</select>
<?php
}
else {
?>
<select name="Select1">
<option></option>
<option>Vault</option>
<option>Uneven Bars</option>
<option>Beam</option>
<option>Floor</option>
</select>
<?php
}          
?>
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: gender in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 54
Line 54: $gender = $_POST['gender'];
The drop down menu doesn't change.

Comment: That fixed the undefined index but the drop box still doesn't change.

Comment: Try to print $_POST['gender']. If is having value: 'male' or 'female', it should work.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score -1):

Write this line at the top of your php file you will not get Notice: Undefined index: gender

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
?>
```